# IFS Crystal Reports Error

Tags: crystal-reports, windows-installer, activex, ifs-erp

In my company, we are using IFS as an ERP solution. In IFS, we are creating Crystal Reports for the reports that is not given by IFS.

The problem is, I am using Windows 7 64 Bit and I need to install runtime files for Crystal Reports. Without this, when I try to get a report, I get this error:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3377689/ifs_cp_error.JPG

I talked some of the former employee and he told me that if I install runtime files for crystal reports, it will solve the problem.

I searched the internet and unable to find any working installer for this. I have an installer, "Crystal Runtime File Setup.msi" but when i try to run it, it seems to extract its components but the setup screen wont show up.

Is it because this installer is for 32 Bit or I have a problem with msi installer ?

Anyhow, is there anything to make it work ?

Comment: Well, actually, it depends on which version of Crystal Reports that IFS uses. If it uses Crystal Reports 2008, you're probably going to need to purchase a full license. That's what we had to do for our ERP solution (Epicor.) I honestly doubt it uses Crystal Reports XI, but if it does, you can easily get the 64-bit runtime from SAP. However, it also requires .NET Framework 4 to work, so you'll need to install that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dll files belong to Crystal Reports in your IFS runtime(crpaig32.dll,CRPE32.DLL,crwrap32.dll,cslibu-2-0-0.dll,....) 
or replace them with the ones in your current installation folder.

Problem occurs there is a conflict between the your reports cryst.version and the dll version of the crystal viewers in IFS runtime folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running IFS Applications versions 8 or 9 (and probably 10), the Crystal runtime installer is on your application server. Point the user's web browser to the home page of your application server, then click on "Add-ons" page. The installer should be a link there.

I found this for IFS 8.1, but I make no guarantee that it's legitimate: http://demo.ifs.com.tr:58080/add-on.html

For version 7.5, the Crystal runtime installer is on the front home page.

This client runtime is no longer available in IFS Cloud where the browser-based Aurena client replaces the .NET-based IFS Enterprise Explorer, even for on-prem "Remote" customers.